# How to check for floating point precision in Double

Tags: c, double, precision

Take this simple function for example.

```
   int checkIfTriangleIsValid(double a, double b, double c) {
      //fix the precision problem
      int c1, c2, c3;
      c1 = a+b>c ? 0 : 1;
      c2 = b+c>a ? 0 : 1;
      c3 = c+a>b ? 0 : 1;
      if(c1 == 0 && c2 == 0 && c3 == 0)
        return 0;
      else {
        printf("%d, %d, %d\n",c1, c2, c3);
        return 1;
      }
   }
```

I place for `a = 1.923`, `b = 59.240`, `c = 61.163`

Now for some reason when I check for the condition in c1 it should give me 1, but instead, it gives me 0. I tried to do a `printf` with `%.30f` and found that the values later changes.

How can I fix this problem?

**EDIT:** I checked the other questions that are similar to mine but they don't even have a double.

Comment: value changes *how*? after many decimals? 64 vs 80-bit floats

Comment: example of .30f% for a+b = 61.163000000000003808509063674137, 
c= 61.162999999999996703081706073135

Comment: See [what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and [is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: I am using c99, not sure about 64vs 80

Comment: it looks like 64 vs 80. If kept in register it can retain 80 bits of precision then on stack it will be cut to 64.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Improve INSERT-per-second performance of SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite)

Comment: Hmm though I guess, from the answers, this is not the case...

Comment: @KamilCuk err... no?

Comment: If you did further investigation or test code, include those results (and the code) rather then make us reproduce your test.  Even without issues of converting real decimal values to _binary floating point_ and back, why would you expect `c1==1` when `a + b` is equal to, not greater then `c`?  The result could be zero or 1.  `double` has precision to 20 significant figures decimal - printing to 30 decimal places has no meaning.  Better perhaps to do `(a+b) - c < EPSILON`, when `EPSILON` is some arbitrarily small error limit, such that you will regard `a + b` to be equal to `c`.

Comment: @Clifford: Printing `double` values to 30 decimal places does have meaning. Floating-point arithmetic is well specified (in general; C implementations’ adherence to good principles is spotty). A skilled practitioner can make use of the full values of `double` objects.

Comment: @Clifford: Recommending comparing with a tolerance in this case is misguided. The code is obviously intended to make a certain distinction, and there is no information about whether a false positive or a false negative is preferable, or even whether either is acceptable at all. There is no basis for expecting a test that allows a false positive for `a + b < c` is appropriate.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - agreed.

Comment: I think however determining something like an epsilon that is universal for all the datatypes that I could add is essential, but I am not sure what the value of it should be.

Comment: @mark I assert that an "epsilon" application is not certainly the right approach  nor needed as [answered below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53025722/2410359).  Without further info on how the result of `checkIfTriangleIsValid()` steers code, an "epsilon" is [misguided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53025480/how-to-check-for-floating-point-precision-in-double/53025722#comment92953547_53025480).

Answer (score 1):

Likely your C implementation uses the IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point format for `double`. When `1.923`, `59.240`, and `61.163` are properly converted to the nearest values representable in `double`, the results are exactly:

- 1.9230000000000000426325641456060111522674560546875,
- 59.24000000000000198951966012828052043914794921875, and
- 61.1629999999999967030817060731351375579833984375.

As you can see, the first two of these sum to more than the third. This means that, by the time you assign these values to `double` objects, they have already been altered in a way that changes their relationship. **No subsequent calculations can repair this, because the original information is gone.**

Since no solution **after** conversion to `double` can work, you need a solution that operates before or instead of conversion to `double`. If you want to compute exactly, or more precisely, with the values 1.923, 59.240, and 61.163, you may need to write your own decimal arithmetic code or find some other code that supports decimal arithmetic. If you only want to work with numbers with three decimal places, then a possible solution is to write some code that reads input such as “59.240” and returns it in an integer object scaled by 1000, so that 59240 is returned. The resulting values could then easily be tested for the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1):

> when I check for the condition in c1 it should give me 1, but instead it gives me 0
>   How can I fix this problem?

Change your expectations.

A typical `double` can represent *exactly* about 2<sup>64</sup> different values.  1.923, 59.240, 61.163 are typically not in that set as `double` is usually encoded in a binary way.  e.g. [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

When `a,b,c` are assigned 1.923, 59.240, 61.163, they get values more like the below which are the closet `double`.

```
a      1.923000000000000042632564145606...
b     59.240000000000001989519660128281...
c     61.162999999999996703081706073135...
```

In my case, the `a`, and `b` both received a slightly higher value than the decimal code form, while `c` received a slightly lower one.

When adding `a+b`, the sum was rounded up, further away from `c`.

```
printf("a+b %35.30f\n", a+b);
a+b   61.163000000000003808509063674137
```

**`a + b > c`** was true, as well as other compares and OP's
`checkIfTriangleIsValid(1.923, 59.240, 61.163)` **should return *valid* (0)** as it is really more like `checkIfTriangleIsValid(1.9230000000000000426..., 59.24000000000000198..., 61.16299999999999670...)`

---

Adding `a+b` is further complicated in that the addition may occur using `double` or `long double` math.  Research `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` for details.  Rounding mode also can affect the final sum.

```
#include <float.h>
printf("FLT_EVAL_METHOD %d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);
```

---

As to an alternative triangle check, subtract the largest 2 values and then compare against the smallest.

> `a > (c-b)` can preserve significantly more precision than `(a+b) > c`.

```
// Assume a,b,c >= 0
int checkIfTriangleIsValid_2(double a, double b, double c) {
  // Sort so `c` is largest, then b, a.
  if (c < b) {
    double t = b; b = c; c = t;
  }
  if (c < a) {
    double t = a; a = c; c = t;
  }
  if (a > b) {
    double t = b; b = a; a = t;
  }
  // So far, no loss of precision is expected due to compares/swaps.
  // Only now need to check a + b >= c for valid triangle

  // To preserve precision, subtract from `c` the value closest to it (`b`).
  return a > (c-b);
}
```

I will review more later as time permits.   This approach significant helps for a precise answer - yet need to assess more edge cases.  It reports a valid triangle `checkIfTriangleIsValid_2(1.923, 59.240, 61.163))`.

`FLT_EVAL_METHOD`, rounding mode and `double` encoding can result in different answers on other platforms.

---

Notes:
It appears a `checkIfTriangleIsValid()` returning 0  means *valid triangle*.
It also appears when the triangle has 0 area, the expected result is 1 or *invalid*.